# Punctuation in "tomorrow" followed by date followed by time

Tags: punctuation, dates

Which is more correct?

> Tomorrow, April 7, at 10:00 a.m.

or:

> Tomorrow, April 7 at 10:00 a.m.

EDIT: This question was prompted by someone telling me that it's incorrect to separate date and time with a comma; therefore I'm not asking about "helped my uncle, Jack, off a horse"-type cases in general, but whether there are any other, specifically date-and-time-related, factors at play here, as that person seemed to suggest. From what I gather, the answer is no. Perhaps I should've made that clearer right away, but I think this question is not a duplicate at least insofar as I was *intending* it to be more specific than the question it's been marked as a dupicate of.

Comment: I would use both commas, because *tomorrow* refers only to the date, not the time. Without the second comma, it looks like *tomorrow* is referring to both the date and the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct punctuation with two nouns?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114017/correct-punctuation-with-two-nouns)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What I'm essentially asking is whether this follows that default punctuation pattern, or there are overriding conventions related specifically to date and time. Which is why I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @freedomcry For more information about dates and times specifically, take a look at this article: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/how-to-punctuate-references-to-dates-and-times/  It addresses this exact case with an example. '...the combination of day, date, and time requires organizational punctuation: “The meeting is scheduled for Wednesday, August 31, at 7 p.m.”'

Comment: And yet you are prepared to accept RaceYouAnytime's answer, which does not carry a reference stating that 'this [particular example] follows that default punctuation pattern'. There have been a lot of questions addressing comma usage around parentheticals.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime This needs to be included in your answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Because with the hostile environment you've created here, I just feel like getting this over with.

Comment: You're saying that ' 
Possible duplicate of Correct punctuation with two nouns?' 'created a hostile environment' (that was the only comment bearing my name that was present when you accepted, and appeared automatically). When I return in a couple of days, I will flag your comment if it is still here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes—carrying as it did a formal stamp of disapproval which, from my previous experience with English SE, I should count myself lucky for dodging long enough to get some answers. There's "showing your effort", and then there's having to jump through extra hoops for literally no reason other than to appease some resident sniper with moderating privileges so that they don't find some thin pretext to disrupt.

Comment: For what it's worth, I added my link to the answer, so that it applies to both comma use rules in general and cases specific to date and time.

Comment: I see that a moderator has put the question on hold as POB in any case. The labelling of this as an appositive is, as you imply, not incontestable, and it's not always considered mandatory to set off all appositives in any case. If you consider 'DailyWritingTips' authoritative enough, it licenses the two commas here, but I'd agree with tchrist that it's essentially a style choice. / I'd argue that contesting close-votes on a personal level ('with the hostile environment you've created here')  is what creates a hostile environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both commas. These are *parenthetical commas*, adding supplemental information about "tomorrow."  Per *The Elements of Style* by Strunk and White, parenthetical commas can sometimes be omitted, but if they're used before a parenthetical phrase, they must be used after it as well.

http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html

On parenthetical comma use:

> ...whether the interruption be slight or considerable... never omit one comma and leave the other.

Since this question is specific to dates and times, it's worth taking a look at this article:

http://www.dailywritingtips.com/how-to-punctuate-references-to-dates-and-times/

It addresses this case with an example:

> ...the combination of day, date, and time requires organizational punctuation: “The meeting is scheduled for Wednesday, August 31, at 7 p.m.”