# Commas surrounding a name

Tags: punctuation, commas, appositives, oxford-comma

I am currently working on an essay, and I have a question about a certain pair of commas. Consider the following sentence:

> *One of my classmates, Simona Stoyanova, and I carried out independent research,  focused on the rotation curve of the Milky Way and dark
>   matter.*

Are the commas, which surround the name Simona Stoyanova, needed. I know that if I haven't mentioned the name before there shouldn't be any commas in this place, but it just feels unnatural to write it without the commas.

Comment: Does https://english.stackexchange.com/q/114017 answer your question?

Comment: It's "correct" but not ideal.  You are using commas to set apart a "parenthetical" phrase, a phrase which could be omitted without changing the syntax of the sentence.  But a better way to phrase your sentence would be "My classmate Simona Stoyanova and I carried out independent research..."  (And there are no doubt other ways to put it.)

Comment: I would put myself second and her first. It's less narcissistic.

Comment: Work on essays has no place here unless the Question is posted for its own sake, out of the essay’s context.
Cluttering Questions with detail, as *… focused on the rotation curve of the Milky Way and dark matter* is confusing, not helpful. What’s the grammatical difference if your joint research focusses on the design of bicycle spokes, please?
Neither Stoyanova’s name nor that she’s your classmate is greatly relevant. Citing a *classmate* makes both appear more junior than you’d presumably like. At worst, call Stoyanova your *colleague* or *collaborator*… More…

Comment: *More…* In the context, the commas would be needed.
What makes you think that if you haven't mentioned the name before, there shouldn't be any commas, please?
Why or how does it feel unnatural to write that without the commas?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - You are wrong on several counts.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I think that the "focused on the ..." part of the sentence is umportant,because I don't state this anywhere else, and I just start explaining how the research was conducted. Theres is no gramatical difference if the research focusses on bicycle spokes,but the meaning is completely different. I believe, her name is important, too because this is the only time I state her it. I really like the suggestion about using another word for classmate but I don't like college.It sounds like it's our job to conduct research. Maybe "My collaborator Simona Stoyanova and I..." sounds better?

Comment: @Lambie - Don't I put her name first when I say "One of my classmates, Simona Stoyanova, and I..."?

Comment: Thanks, Hot Licks, and I suggest you are mistaken, on all those counts.

Shall we play pots and kettles, or will you list my errors?

Comment: Are you happy to accept that nothing about an essay can be considered here, as such?

Comment: How could you ignore the meanings of *focused* or *important*?

What difference could research make to whether names should be surrounded by commas? 

Bicycle spokes should merely show detail is obstructive.

Of course her name is important and if you understood the common practises of Academe, you’d know the names of colleagues should have be cited in the title statements. Leaving any of them to be mentioned in the general text would be at best insulting, as every qualified college senior has a clear and simple duty to tell you.

More…

Comment: When ’it sounds like it's our job to conduct research’ are you not a student?

Do students not have, broadly, two duties? As juniors, to listen then as seniors, to listen and to conduct research?

What else do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

The commas indicate an *appositive:* an elucidation: “James, the baker”, as opposed to an exonym. See also epergesis: Interposing an apposition, often in order to clarify what has just been stated. "I saw you right over there, that is, in my office, rummaging through my desk."

Perhaps reordering might make it feel better

Simona Stoyanova, one of my classmates, ...

Now the appositive describes the person rather than the other way around

Answer (score 0):

The commas indicate additional information which is not necessary but adds context to the sentence (neutral). If the author is adding superfluous information then they would use brackets, while vital information is indicated by dashes (-).